# How to check if supervisor process is running or stopped using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, supervisord

I run multiple supervisor processes sometimes due to server overload some processes **Stop** indefinitely until you manually restart them. Is there a way I can write a bash script that can be regularly executed by a crontab to check the process that has stopped and restart it.

This how I can check status, stop or restart a process on a terminal

```
root@cloud:~# supervisorctl status birthday-sms:birthday-sms_00
birthday-sms:birthday-sms_00     RUNNING   pid 2696895, uptime 0:02:08
root@cloud:~# supervisorctl stop birthday-sms:birthday-sms_00
birthday-sms:birthday-sms_00: stopped
root@cloud:~# supervisorctl status birthday-sms:birthday-sms_00
birthday-sms:birthday-sms_00     STOPPED   May 07 11:07 AM
```

I don't want use crontab to restart all at a certain interval `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/supervisorctl restart all` but I want to check and restart stopped processes only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make and test a script without crontab that performs the actions you want.
When the script is working, check that it still runs without the settings in your `.bashrc`, such as the path to `supervisorctl`.
Also check that your script doesn't write to stdout, perhaps introduce a logfile.
Next add the script to crontab.

```
#!/bin/bash
for proc in 'birthday-sms:birthday-sms_00' 'process2' 'process3'; do
  # Only during development, you don't want output from cron
  echo "Checking ${proc}"
  status=$(supervisorctl status "${proc}" 2>&1)
  echo "$status"
  if [[ "$status" == *STOPPED* ]]; then
    echo "Restarting ${proc}"
    supervisorctl restart "${proc}"
  fi
done
```

or using an array and shorter testing

```
#!/bin/bash
processes=('birthday-sms:birthday-sms_00' 'process2' 'process3')
for proc in ${processes[@]}; do
  supervisorctl status "${proc}" 2>&1 |
    grep -q STOPPED &&
    supervisorctl restart "${proc}"
done
```

Comment: Both methods works as expected, thanks